# Ngrx filtered reducer with aot

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm trying to use this reducer from [ReduxJs site](http://redux.js.org) with NgRx and Angular Cli:

```
function createFilteredReducer(reducerFunction, reducerPredicate) {
    return (state, action) => {
        const isInitializationCall = state === undefined;
        const shouldRunWrappedReducer = reducerPredicate(action) || isInitializationCall;
        return shouldRunWrappedReducer ? reducerFunction(state, action) : state;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error with prod build:

> ERROR in app/app.module.ts(504,29): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
>     Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'reducers'
>       'reducers' contains the error at app/reducers/index.ts(106,9)
>         Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.

Do you have any ideas how can I achieve this functionality with a code that compiles in prod mode?

Comment: did you solve it somehow?
I found this , but it didn't solvr it for me..
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/116

Comment: Sadly no I was not able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with help of a friend.
try :

```
export function createFilteredReducer(reducerFunction, reducerPredicate) {
```

at app.module

```
import { StoreModule, ActionReducerMap, State } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { createFilteredReducer} from './redux/reducer';


imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot({ createFilteredReducer}),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25 //  Retains last 25 states
    })
  ]
```